I want to create a custom filter in odoo web
I want to create a custom filter in odoo web to filter the Check_in date in odoo attendance app online version.
I want to show record from the 26th to the 25th of each month.
Example : 26-07-2024 to 25-08-2024
i Entered this code but it wouldnt work
"[
    ('check_in', '>=', (context_today()+datetime.timedelta(days =1)-.replace(day=26)),
    ('check_in', '<=', context_today()+datetime.timedelta(days=25)
)
]"



Error is :  This domain is not supported.   or I get "not a valid
datetime"


Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Refer below code
   <filter string="Last Week" name="week" domain="[('date_order','&gt;', (context_today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))]"/>

I hoe this will resolve your issue.
